# I'm trying to scrape a Bing dict page with BeautifulSoup. However, response.content doesn't contain the actual data, how do I do?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a Bing dict page https://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=avengers

Here is the code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = "https://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=avengers"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

examples = soup.find_all("div", class_="sen_en b_regtxt")

for example in examples:
    print(example.text.strip())
```

In particular, I'm trying scrape all the example sentences on that page, which is contained in a `div` with class `sen_en b_regtxt`

However, `response.content` doesn't even contain one example sentence in it, what am I missing?

PS, access to the page doesn't need login

[image]

With @Artur Chukhrai's help, I also tried with selenium and I got "No results found for avenger"

[image]

However, if I access the url "cn.bing.com/dict" first, and then put the keyword in the search box, I would get the result page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small modification to [Arthur Chukhrai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18597245/artur-chukhrai)'s answer works, by loading https://cn.bing.com/dict and then writing the text in the search box:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://cn.bing.com/dict/"

# Start a new Selenium web driver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Write text in search box
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="b_searchbox")
search_box.send_keys("avengers\n")

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Get the page source after it has fully loaded
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Find and print the examples of the word
examples = soup.select(".sen_en")
for example in examples:
    print(example.text.strip())

# Quit the web driver instance
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Access to the content of this site can only be obtained by those users who are authorized:

[image: authorized]

If you open the link in incognito mode, you will get the same information that your script gets:

[image: incognito]

In order to implement authorization to the site, you can use automation tools. You can work with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).

Also wanted to point out that you can use one of the options below to access the items you are looking for:

```py
# first variant
examples = soup.find_all("div", class_="sen_en")
# second variant
examples = soup.select(".sen_en")
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think login is the key, I've updated my OP.

Comment: I have added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75839394/18597245)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it looks different on my computer.

Since I cannot check the code on my side, I offer you 2 solutions.

Here's an updated code snippet that uses the `requests` and `json` modules to scrape the example sentences from the Bing dictionary page:

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://cn.bing.com/ttranslatev3"

params = {
    'fromLang': 'en',
    'to': 'zh-CHS'
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "your-api-key"
}

data = {
    'text': 'avengers'
}

response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
translation = json.loads(response.text)['translation'][0]['text']

url = "https://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=" + translation

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

examples = soup.select(".sen_en")

for example in examples:
    print(example.text.strip())
```

This code uses the `requests` module to send a request to the Bing Translate API and get the Chinese translation of the word "avengers". It then constructs a new URL for the Bing dictionary page using the translated word, sends a request to that URL, and uses BeautifulSoup to scrape the example sentences from the page.

Note that you will need to replace `"your-api-key"` with your actual Bing Translate API key in the `headers` dictionary for this code to work.

To use the Bing Translate API, you need to sign up for a Microsoft Azure account and subscribe to the Microsoft Translator Text API service. Here's how you can obtain the API key:

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
2. If you don't have an Azure account, sign up for a free trial.
3. Create a new Translator Text API resource:

   1. Search for "Translator Text API" in the search bar.
   2. Click on the "Create" button.
   3. Enter the required information, such as the subscription, resource group, and resource name.
   4. Choose a pricing tier and location.
   5. Click on the "Create" button.
4. Once the resource is created, go to the "Keys and Endpoint" tab and copy one of the keys listed under "KEY 1" or "KEY 2".

You can then use the copied key as the value for the "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" header in your requests to the Bing Translate API.

---

Here's an example code snippet that uses `Selenium` and `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the examples of the word "avengers" from the Bing dictionary page:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=avengers"

# Start a new Selenium web driver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Get the page source after it has fully loaded
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Find and print the examples of the word
examples = soup.select(".sen_en")
for example in examples:
    print(example.text.strip())

# Quit the web driver instance
driver.quit()
```

This code uses the `webdriver` class from Selenium to start a new Chrome web driver instance, navigate to the Bing dictionary page for the word "avengers", wait for the page to fully load, and then scrape the examples of the word using BeautifulSoup. Finally, it quits the web driver instance to free up system resources.

Note that you will need to install the Selenium package and the Chrome driver executable for this code to work. You can download the latest version of the Chrome driver from the [official website](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

I hope one of these 2 solutions will help you! Let me know if you have any questions or need further assistance.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code with selenium and got "No results found for avenger". However, if I access the url "https://cn.bing.com/dict/" first, and then put the keyword in the search box, I would get the result page.